# REST security, is a bad practice to use basic auth plus jwt token verification?

Tags: rest, security, jwt, basic-authentication

I'm making a secure rest service and I've already secured it using basic auth plus a jwt token that's obtained before, am I making the security too strong or it's that a necessary path to follow?

Comment: What do you mean you use both? Basic auth authenticates every single request you make using the `Authorization: Basic <payload>` header. After you have done this, you authenticate again and generate a JWT token? Or is the token generated based on basic auth? Where do you put it? Into `Authorization: Bearer <payload>`. Do you have both headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using both HTTP Basic auth and JWT token does not make the application more secure, it actually makes it less secure and more complex to handle.

HTTP Basic auth is done by the user agent (usually a browser). It permanently adds the `Authorization: Basic <payload>` header to every request. You can not log out. It will be there unless you close the agent. The only good thing is that this authentication can be invalidated. And we usually don't use this authentication for humans, but for microservices only due to the poor handling in the browsers (forget to close the tab and log out and you're done if someone gets physical access to your computer).

JWT is a bit better. It can expire. But can not be invalidated (without setting up additional infrastructure at least).

Now what you get is the worst of the two worlds. You can not log out. If your JWT token expires it will be regenerated as you still have Basic Auth. If you invalidate basic auth, you might (maybe - would need to check it to be 100% sure) still access the app using the JWT token until it expires.

Do not take my word for that. Just check if after the JWT token expires, you still can access the app and what happens with the JWT token then.

I once had basic auth and normal authentication using JSESSIONID. The mix did not work either.

Comment: In case that the jwt its generated not only by the user credentials but it's generated by an id plus the credentials, it's still too bad used both ways of security?

Comment: How is the id passed? Is it something the user provides? Is it something taken automatically from - say - database?

Comment: it's pass as value in the URL of the get request

Comment: IMHO this does not change much. An attacker can use this id field just like a normal user does.